# Struct padding rules in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, padding

Recently when I was learning [Type Layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html) in Rust, I saw that struct in Rust supports the #[repr(C)] directive, so I want to to see the difference between the default (Rust) representation and C-like representation. Here comes the code:

```
use type_layout::TypeLayout;

#[derive(TypeLayout)]
struct ACG1 {
    time1: u16, // 2
    time2: u16, // 2
    upper: u32, // 4
    lower: u16, // 2
}

#[derive(TypeLayout)]
#[repr(C)]
struct ACG2 {
    time1: u16, // 2
    time2: u16, // 2
    upper: u32, // 4
    lower: u16, // 2
}

fn main() {
    println!("ACG1: {}", ACG1::type_layout());
    println!("ACG2: {}", ACG2::type_layout());
}
```

And I get the following output:

[image]

I understand the rules for padding the #[repr(C)] structure and the size of the structure as a whole, but what confused me is the Rust representation struct ACG1. I can't find any clear documentation on Rust padding rules, and I think the padding size should also be included in the overall size of the structure, but why is the size of ACG1 only 12 bytes?

BTW, this is the crate I used to assist in printing the layout of the structure: *[type-layout
0.2.0](https://crates.io/crates/type-layout)*

Comment: Maybe an issue with the crate? It's a bit confusing because the crate's readme says *"This crate works on non-#[repr(C)] types, but their layout is unpredictable."*, but the crate author has [this open issue](https://github.com/LPGhatguy/type-layout/issues/4) on his repo that states, *"The crate today doesn't really work on non-repr(C) types."*

Comment: Behind the scenes, the size is simply initialized with a call to `std::mem::size_of::<Type>()`, and `std::mem::size_of::<ACG1>()` does indeed return 12. See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.size_of.html#size-of-structs) for how the size of a struct is calculated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This crate does not seem to account for field reordering. It appears the compiler reordered the struct to have `upper` first:

```
struct ACG1 {
    upper: u32,
    time1: u16,
    time2: u16,
    lower: u16,
}
```

It’s somewhat hard to see, but the [derive macro implementation](https://github.com/LPGhatguy/type-layout/blob/main/type-layout-derive/src/lib.rs) checks the difference between fields *in declared order*. So in this sense, there *are* four bytes of "padding" between the beginning of the struct and the first field (`time1`) and four bytes of "padding" between the third field (`upper`) and fourth field (`lower`).

There is [an issue](https://github.com/LPGhatguy/type-layout/issues/4) filed that it doesn't work for non-`#[repr(C)]` structs, so I would not recommend using this crate for this purpose.

As far as Rust's rules go, the reference says *"There are no guarantees of data layout made by [the default] representation."* So in theory, the compiler can do whatever it wants and reorder fields based on access patterns. But in practice, I don't think it’s that elaborate and organizing by field size is a simple way to minimize padding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for pointing out the problem with this crate. What I actually want to know is: what rules does Rust's compiler use to lay out a structure, because my previous language was C++, so I'm trying to figure out something more fundamental; but when I check Rust's documentation, it seems that the richest explanation for the layout of a structure is that the layout of a structure is unstable and unobservable, so I'm a bit difficult to accept

Comment: *"what rules does Rust's compiler use to lay out a structure"* - there are no rules! Beyond things like alignment and obvious things like fields can't overlap, the compiler can do what it wants. Currently though, the implementation in [`compiler/rustc_middle/src/ty/layout.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/59337cddd41880f8075b07860a99be4dc402ddb1/compiler/rustc_middle/src/ty/layout.rs) just orders higher-alignment fields first. But I believe it is left unspecified to allow changes or optimizations in the future. Rust and C++ are quite different in how the languages are developed.

Comment: Strange how the crate mishandles compiler reordering because you should be able to find the offsets (accounting for reordering, padding and all) using `std::ptr::addr_of()`; however, I guess that was introduced relatively recently.

Comment: I have found some useful links: 
1. https://camlorn.net/posts/April%202017/rust-struct-field-reordering
2. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37429
These articles explain why and how rust does this, and those interested in this issue may find useful information here

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, it seem to be an issue in the crate.
Better ask the compiler:

```
cargo clean
cargo rustc -- -Zprint-type-sizes
```

This will give you:

```
...
print-type-size type: `ACG1`: 12 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.upper`: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.time1`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     field `.time2`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     field `.lower`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     end padding: 2 bytes
print-type-size type: `ACG2`: 12 bytes, alignment: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.time1`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     field `.time2`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     field `.upper`: 4 bytes
print-type-size     field `.lower`: 2 bytes
print-type-size     end padding: 2 bytes
```